Не запускается дискорд бот при переходе на новый пк
После перехода с Windows 10 на новый ПК на Windows 11 выдает вот такую ошибку:
C:\Users\n\Desktop\ds_bot>python t3.py
[2024-07-26 16:46:26] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 992, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1147, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1180, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 578, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 560, in _do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\ssl.py", line 917, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\n\Desktop\ds_bot\t3.py", line 1952, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 685, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 777, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 612, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 803, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 625, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1194, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 578, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 911, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1235, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1204, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 994, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')]

Предложенные решения не помогли:

Обновить aiohttp до версии минимум 4.7.1: upgrading to aiohttp > 3.7.0
Установить требуемые сертификаты локально на ПК: Windows
Обновить корневые сертификаты Windows: статья


У Вас проблема с проверкой сертификата SSL и по данному вопросу есть несколько возможных решений:

Обновить aiohttp до версии минимум 4.7.1 - upgrading to aiohttp > 3.7.0

Установить требуемые сертификаты локально на ПК:
Windows
Mac

Обновить корневые сертификаты всего Windows:
Статья



попробовал ничего так и не заработало

На какую именно систему Вы перешли? Возможно стоит в целом в системе обновить корневые сертификаты.

до этого бот был на ноуте по виндовс10 а перешел на пк под виндовс11, на ноуте не устанавливался питон и я помоему портативную версию установил так и делал бота, а на новом компе чистая виндовс11

Можно попробовать обновить корневые сертификаты: статья - хотя на Windows они должны обновляться автоматически. Ещё можете попробовать установить Python вместо использования портативной - возможно прошлая ошибка не воспроизведется

после перехода на новый пк питон установился без проблем, а в данной статье на первом этапе уже ничего не работает

В итоге спустя время нашел вот такой способ, который помог решить проблему с корневыми сертификатами виндовс.
не знаю, чем отличается найденый способ то этого - Обновить корневые сертификаты Windows - но он помог решить беду.

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.

@aleksandrbarakin если так необходимо могу вставить в ответ команды которые использовал
